# Show $D(T)= \{x=(\epsilon_j) \in l^2 : \sum^\infty_{j=1} |\lambda _j |^2 |\epsilon _j |^2 <\infty \}$ is a dense subspace of $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(\lambda_n)$ be a sequence of non-zero scalers and let

$D(T)= \{x=(\epsilon_j) \in l^2 : \sum^\infty_{j=1} |\lambda _j |^2 |\epsilon _j |^2 <\infty \}$

We define a linear operator $D(T) \to Ran(T)$,  $D(T) \in l^2$ and $Ran(T) \in l^2$ , as

$Tx= T(\epsilon_j)^\infty_1=(\lambda _j \epsilon _j)^\infty _1$, $x=(\epsilon_j) \in D(T)$

I am trying to show that both $D(T$ and $Ran(T)$ are dense subspaces of $l^2$ and that $T$ has an inverse.

It is almost trivial to show that $T$ has an inverse.

To show that both $D(T)$ and $Ran(T)$ are dense subspaces of $l^2$, the solution just says that from the inverse it is clear that both $D(T)$ and $Ran(T)$ contain the space of all finitely non zero sequences which is dense in $l^2$.

> What does this mean?
>
> Is their a more clearer proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$ l_{00}^2:=\{ (x_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \in l^2 : \text{all but finitely many } x_i \text{ are } 0\}. $$

It is not difficult to prove that this is a subspace of $l^2$. The nice thing about this subspace is, that although is look "small", it lies dense in $l^2$. Indeed, let $x=(x_1, x_2, \dots)\in l^2$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define

$$ x^{(n)}:=(x_1, \dots, x_n, 0, 0, \dots) \in l_{00}^2.$$

We calculate

$$ \Vert x - x^{(n)} \Vert_{l^2}^2=\sum_{k\geq n+1} \vert x_k\vert^2 \rightarrow 0, \quad \text{for } n\rightarrow \infty.$$

Hence, $l_{00}^2$ lies dense in $l^2.$ Back to your question. Check that $l_{00}^2\subseteq D(T)$ and $l_{00}^2\subseteq Ran(T).$

From point-set topology we know that for a topological space $X$ with subsets $A, B \subseteq X$ holds

$$A\subseteq B \Rightarrow \overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}. $$

Then we get

$$ l^2= \overline{l_{00}^2} \subseteq \overline{D(T)}\subseteq l^2.$$

Hence, $\overline{D(T)}=l^2$, i.e. $D(T)$ lies dense in $l^2$. The same argument shows that $Ran(T)$ lies dense in $l^2$ as well.

Comment: what does $l^2 _{00}$ mean?

Comment: Usually one writes (compare here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) $c_{00}$ for this set. However, I wanted to stress that we think about it as a subset of $l^2$. Of course you may name it any way you like :)